# Apex cron job command to schedule an apex job to run every 4 hours daily

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, scheduled

I have a requirement where i need to run an apex batch job every 4 hours daily monday to friday and all months in a year. I looked at the apex cron job documentation to be setup using code snippets in execute anonymous window. But it is not very clear. I am not sure whether i can do this through the gui but i would like to atleast do this through the system.schedule at run time is fine. Could you guys give me exact syntax for the cron please?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you use the following chron string for your scheduled job, it will run every 4 hours (at set times) Monday through Friday.

```
apexScheduledJob j = new apexScheduledJob ();
String sch = '0 0 0,4,8,12,16,20 ? * MON-FRI';
System.schedule('My Job', sch, j);
```

If you wanted it to run every day, you would just change it to

```
String sch = '0 0 0,4,8,12,16,20 ? * *';
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. What is the syntax   to run all days of the week ?

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect

Comment: No prob.  Glad it helped

Comment: Curiously, the [V44 doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm?search_text=schedule) says you can't use commas in the hours place for the Cron expression yet it works

Answer (score 3):

use this site to make cron for every scenario.
[cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)