# How to specify the below in System.schedule Method in salesforce

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, scheduled

I want to write in apex code below of the following to use in System.schedule Method.
For Daily i can use this

```
String sch = '0 0 00 ? * MON-FRI';
```

How would I schedule a job with the following criteria?

1. Weekly
2. Every 15 days
3. Monthly

Comment: Gothrough the http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system.schedule argument to represent the Date and time of the job is a bit quirky at first, but once you get the hang of it, its really quite simple

To answer you immediate question

**Weekly** *(Here it is set up to run every Saturday at 8am, but you can adjust which day of the week by changing the 6th element, which happens to be a 6 for Saturday)*

```
String sch = '0 0 8 * * 6'
```

**Every 15 Days** *(Here I have the job running on the 1st and 15th of each month)*

```
String sch = '0 0 00 1,15 * ?'
```

**Monthly** *(This runs at 8 am on the last day of the month)*

```
string sch = '0 0 8 L * ?'
```

Take a look at the docs here

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm

Have a similar question I answered here for a different time period, but same general concept

[Apex cron job command to schedule an apex job to run every 4 hours daily](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16841/apex-cron-job-command-to-schedule-an-apex-job-to-run-every-4-hours-daily)