# Is it reliable to use undocumented feature to schedule a batch every X hours?

Tags: scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, scheduled-job, scheduled, schedule

I need some job to be run on schedule every x hours.
I see that [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) claims that ***none*** special characters are allowed for hours portion of CRON expression, however, when I try on sandbox to execute the following code

```
System.schedule('Run Batch every five hours', '0 0 2/5 * * ?', new BatchScheduler('Batch') );
```

I don't receive any error or exception and it seems to be scheduling it every 5 hours. Since this is not documented I am not sure if I could rely on this to run on production.

Can I rely upon this undocumented feature to use in production code?

Comment: U can never rely on undocumented observations. They can change / cease to work at any time

Comment: However, these undocumented observations are suggested as an answer to another questions https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16841/apex-cron-job-command-to-schedule-an-apex-job-to-run-every-4-hours-daily?rq=1

Comment: I am not agreeing or disagreeing with you on the undocumented part. And yes there are answers like that everywhere. It does not change my comment.